# Read xml from URL

Tags: c#, xml

This is what I have so far.  I am trying to just read the XML from the URL and just get for example temperature, humidity....etc.... But every time I try something else it gives me an error.  I want to retrieve the information and put it in a label.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            String zip = txtZip.Text;
            XmlDocument weatherURL = new XmlDocument();
            weatherURL.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/"
            your_key "/conditions/q/" + zip + ".xml");
            foreach(XmlNode nodeselect in weatherURL.SelectNodes("response/current_observation"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show an example of how the XML looks like and what precise information you are trying to parse from it.

Comment: "it gives me an error" is never enough information - see http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: <response><version>0.1</version><termsofService>http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html</termsofService><features></features><current_observation><image></image><display_location></display_location><observation_location></observation_location><local_tz_short>PST</local_tz_short><local_tz_long>America/Los_Angeles</local_tz_long><local_tz_offset>-0800</local_tz_offset><weather>Mostly Cloudy</weather><temperature_string>72 F (22.2 C)</temperature_string>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It took me a bit of trial and error but I've got it.  In C# make sure you are using - ***using System.Xml;***

Here is the code using wunderground API.  In order for this to work make sure you sign up for a key other wise it will not work.  Where is say this your_key that is where you put in your key.  It should look like something like this. I used a button and three labels to display the information.

```
namespace wfats2

{

  public partial class Form1 : Form

{

 public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/your_key/conditions/q/92135.xml");
            XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/response/current_observation");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                string tempf = node["temp_f"].InnerText;
                string tempc = node["temp_c"].InnerText;
                string feels = node["feelslike_f"].InnerText;

                label2.Text = tempf;
                label4.Text = tempc;
                label6.Text = feels;
            }



        }
    }
}
```

When you press the button you will get the information displayed in the labels assign.  I am still experimenting and you are able to have some sort of refresh every so often instead of pressing the button every time to get an update.

Answer (score 0):

First off yeah you need to give more information in your question but off hand I can see that you have "your_key" inside of your URL. You are probably needing to replace that with your API key for this to work.

Comment: I have a key but do not know which parameter to use to get certain elements.   (did not want to put my key out for everybody to use)

Comment: foreach (XmlNode nodeselect in weatherURL.SelectNodes("response/current_observation")); doesn't do anything else. What error are you getting, and what are you trying to do? Supply a sample of the xml that you are getting and what fields you want.